# Install php7-fpm in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, server, php, php-fpm

I'm trying to install php7-fpm in my Ubuntu VPS. 
I've tried

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Then, I did

**service php7-fpm status**

```
● php7-fpm.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

---

**/etc/init.d/php-7.0.7-fpm start**

```
-bash: /etc/init.d/php-7.0.7-fpm: No such file or directory
```

---

**php -v**

```
PHP 7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.8-4+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

---

How do I properly install it ? and test if it is running ?

Comment: Are you sure php7.0 installs php7.0-fpm? I would assume you also need to install php7.0-fpm.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `php -v` show that I have/using the 7 one. `php7.0-fpm` is what I am trying to install correct.

Comment: Why are you running PHP 7 from a third party repository?  What Ubuntu are you on?  (PHP 7 is default PHP version in Ubuntu)  Note that `php7.0-fpm` is what you need to install, not `php7.0` and nothing else.

Answer (score 4):

do `dpkg -l | grep fpm` to confirm if you have `php7.0-fpm` installed. If not, install it manually:

`sudo apt install php7.0-fpm`

Answer (score 0):

The service is called `php7.0-fpm` as you would get by listing the contents of the package:

```
dpkg -L php7.0-fpm | grep -E "/etc/init|/lib/systemd"
```